# Time a web request

Tags: python, time

Here is how I am calculating the entire time to do a request:

```
import time
t1 = time.time()
r = requests.get('www.mysite.com')
t2 = time.time()
print 'Time of request: %s' (t2-t1)
```

How would I track the following times with a url/view that I own:

- Time it takes from the time it is sent on the client's machine to the time it is received by the web server.
- Time it takes to execute the view.
- Time it takes to send back the data.
- Total time (I already have this from above).

I am thinking if I could sync the times, I could do something like:

```
start_time = time.time()
r = requests.get('www.mysite.com?start_time=start_time')
data = r.json()
end_time = time.time() - start_time
print '''
TimeToReceiveRequest: %s
TimeToExecuteView: %s
TimeToReturnRequest: %s
TotalTime: %s''' % (
  data['time_to_receive_request'], 
  data['time_to_execute_view']
  end_time - data['time_to_receive_request'] - data['time_to_execute_view']
  end_time - start_time
)
```

And in the view --

```
# in the view
def view(request):
    data = {}
    data['time_to_receive_request'] = time.time() - request.GET['start_time']
    # do something in view
    data['time_to_execute_view'] = time.time() - time_to_get_request
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

How would I then sync the `times`, so this would work in both places?

Comment: In general it is very difficult to sync clocks between 2 machines. I would suggest splitting the measurements in two: 
1. Roundtrip of request/response as seen by the client (this gives you accurate results, because it only uses client clock)
2. Total processing time on the server (also accurate, because it only uses server clock)
Then you can subtract the two to see how much you've spent on the network and in the client stack and how much you've spent on the server

Comment: What would be some ways to sync it?

Comment: I've edited my previous comment to add the two measurements. You don't want to sync clocks, because the network latency will introduce inaccuracies which can not be accounted for. It is best to use roundtrips, because they measure everything from the point of view of a single clock.